# Is Arcane Orb viable for a battle Wizard?

Tags: diablo-iii

As I said before, I'm playing a battle Wizard and I'm trying to figure out the best skills.  Arcane Orb and its Arcane Orbit rune look very promising!

I don't have the ability yet.  I want to know if it's spammable and how close the enemies have to get exactly?  I assume you can walk while using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very viable, specially with the passive that slows enemies down when using arcane skills. Certainly helps with kiting on hell and inferno.

Answer (score 1):

[Arcane orb's](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/arcane-orb) arcane orbit is hitting enemies in close to melee range. You will have to walk up pretty closely to actually get the orbs hit your opponents.

It is not spammable so to speak but you can recast it whenever your orbs are all exploded to maximize it's damage. I wouldn't suggest to focus on this skill as your main resource spender but it's a nice addition for a melee wizard.